# Indicating that the returned instance is a derived class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

i have a function which returns an instance of class derived from RLMObject (can return different class instances, but all derived from RLMObject)

```
- (nullable RLMObject *)importObject:(nonnull NSDictionary *)object;
```

so i currently use it as

```
Rating * realmObject = (Rating *)[self createOrImport:object];
```

**but i know there is a way of doing it without the cast, just by implicating, that the returned value is a derived class from RLMObject, so i can use it like**

```
Rating * realmObject = [self createOrImport:object];
```

this can be done with the id, but i want to be more specific, than using just the id... smth. as

```
- (nullable derived RLMObject *)importObject:(nonnull NSDictionary *)object;
```

Comment: In each derived class, you could override `importObject:` and specify the return object class, and in it, just call `[super createOrImport:object]`?

Comment: naah, i remember there was a keyword for this i stumbled uppon by accident, but cannot find it again

Comment: the magic keyword was __kindof

Answer (score 1):

__kindof is the magic keyword

```
- (nullable __kindof RLMObject *)importObject:(nonnull NSDictionary *)object;
```

found out because of a storyboard method

```
- (__kindof UIViewController *)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```